# Responsive media queries using em

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've seen various media queries designed to determinate the layout, but lately i been seeing people find the screen size using *em*.

Is this better, and why?

Comment: I don't think using `em` is a good idea, unless the designer wants something different than the responsive design.

Comment: Here's an article explaining the benefits of using ems: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Answer (score 1):

Use **em** to make scalable style sheets. em is a relative measurement of your browser same as percentage unit.

#### Example

```
body {
  font-size: 81.25%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 68em) and (min-height: 53em) {
  body {
    font-size: 87.5%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 75em) and (min-height: 57em) {
  body {
    font-size: 93.75%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 80em) and (min-height: 62em) {
  body {
    font-size: 100%;
  }
}
```

EM units and then changing body’s font-size when viewport height grows above certain point. you [read this](http://viljamis.com/blog/2012/scaling-with-em-units/) to clear idea how em does work. hope this help you!